# "An Error Occurred" when adding a tag description/excerpt

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-wiki, tag-excerpt

I noticed that the [tkmessagebox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tkmessagebox) tag doesn't have an excerpt or description, so I tried to add the following:

> The tkMessageBox module is part of the Tk GUI toolkit. It handles the
>   creation of pop-up message boxes to show information or present a
>   choice to the user.

Unfortunately, I got an "An Error Occurred" message when I tried to submit it. The [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tkmessagebox/info) now shows an "edit pending" message, but there is nothing in [my activity history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4200092/gobusto?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) to indicate that it was me who made the edit. So, my questions are:

- Has this happened because someone else edited that tag at the same time as me? If so, then surely the error message should be clarified to explain that my edit could not be submitted due to an *edit conflict* rather than a general "error".
- Alternatively, has *my* edit been processed, but not appeared on my activity feed due to an error? If so, then it would appear to be a bug.

**EDIT:** It seems that this was due to an edit conflict. As such, I've re-tagged this as a feature request. As stated above, I believe that the error message should be clarified to explain that the edit could not be submitted due to an *edit conflict* rather than a general "error".

Comment: [Someone else suggested an edit.](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6968692)

Comment: A timing coincidence, then? OK, thanks for clearing that up. As I mentioned, though, I'd suggest that it might be worth clarifying the reason for the failure to avoid confusion in the future.

Answer (score 1):

We now show more specific error messages for various failure conditions in suggested tag wiki edits.

In this specific case, the error shown would be

> Another edit is awaiting approval for this post. Further edits cannot be submitted until the pending edit is reviewed.