# A bit more helpful message instead of "an error occurred"

Tags: feature-request, tag-wiki

I was trying to add this description to an empty tag after a friendly invite to add missing content.

So I thought up some stuff to add there to make it more descriptive:

[image]

I found this:
*["An Error Occurred" when adding a tag description/excerpt](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285517/an-error-occurred-when-adding-a-tag-description-excerpt)*

In cases like this, can we get to see the pending request for voting instead of this non-descriptive message? Or at least a message "This tag wiki already has a pending request"

Comment: It is the kind of error reporting that was made for normal people.  Programmers use their browser's developer tools to see the error 500 reason.  You ought to see the value of the .NET Exception.Message property.

Comment: An error occurred trying to research the underlying cause. Attempt to turn off user-friendly error messages failed for the following reason: an error occurred.

Comment: I just got this error trying to edit [tag:textmate2] and I see no indication there is a pending edit anywhere on the page. It hasn't been edited in 3 years, so the chances of there being a conflict seem low.

Comment: @HansPassant In my case there is a 302 redirect to http://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/edit-tag-wiki/submit/75795 which provides no details aside from a picture of a cat at a keyboard. Intimating someone isn't a "real" programmer because they expect a user-friendly error message is not a helpful response.

Comment: @HansPassant Real programmers use [butterflies](https://xkcd.com/378/).

Comment: Thank you all for reminding me that I suck, needs to be re-inforced once in a while so one doesn't get too uppity.  Sorry, I do converse a lot with normal people every day, I already know it is a liability.

Comment: You should add the word “backend” to your user dictionary. This reduces the likelihood of overlooking real spell errors.